# Primefaces Accordion Tab empty when rendered="true"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, accordion

I had a perfectly working accordion with forms and datatables, until I decided to hide some tabs according to a get param. For example `/editarContrato.jsf?id=19`

Now the rendered tabs appear but empty. I now the boolen is correctly evaluated, and that the tab header is showing when it should, but not the content.

Thanks!

```
<p:accordionPanel multiple="true" dynamic="true" cache="false"
id="mainAccordion">
<p:tab title="#{msg['label.contrato']}" id="mainTab">
    <h:form styleClass="form-horizontal" id="form">

    </h:form>
</p:tab>
<p:tab title="Plan de Pagos" rendered="#{not empty param.id}">
    <h:form styleClass="form-horizontal" id="formPago">
        <p:dataTable id="dataPagos" value="#{pagoMB.dataPagos}" var="pago"
            editable="true" ajax="true" royKey="#{pago.id}" scrollable="true"
            scrollWidth="100%" rows="10" paginator="true"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" style="table-layout: auto">
            <f:facet name="header">Plan de Pagos
                </f:facet>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</p:tab>
```

Comment: Instead of directly/implicitly fetching a request parameter value through `param.id`, set it first to a managed bean property through `<f:viewParam>`, `@ManagedProperty(value="#{param.id}")` (available only in request scoped JSF managed beans) or whatever that suits your needs. You should not use multiple `<h:form>`s for every single `<p:tab>` unless they are absolutely necessary. You can, if necessary, always partially process/update components via AJAX instead of processing/updating the whole `<h:form>` in question.

Comment: Wrap the contents of the tab in an `outputPanel` with `autoUpdate="true"`. Look into your javascript console now to see if there's anything in the markup at all, under that tab. Also look for ajax errors

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<p:tab title="Plan de Pagos" rendered="#{not empty param['id']}">
```

Param is a map of values and id can't be resolved this way.